# PowerShellでテキストから正規表現を用いて特定の数値を抜き出し四則演算を行いたい

Tags: 正規表現, powershell

hoge.txt

```
hoge0500huge4600telssae0700
hoge0600huge4700telssae0800fdef
```

例えばこの様なテキストがあったとして

```
^hoge0(\d{1,})huge4(\d{1,})telssae0(\d{1,})(.*)?$
```

この様な正規表現を用いて特定の数字を取得して、その数値に四則演算を行いテキストとして出力したいです。

イメージとしてはこのような感じです。

```
$x = 2
（正規表現）
^hoge0(\d{1,})huge4(\d{1,})telssae0(\d{1,})(.*)?$
$AA = $1 / $x
$AB = $2 / $x
$AC = $3 / $x
（テキスト出力）
hoge0$AAhuge4$ABtelssae0$AC$4
（出力結果）
hoge0250huge4300telssae0350
hoge0300huge4350telssae0400fdeffdef
```

どのようにすればよいか教えて頂けると幸いです。

補足

```
$WARU = 2
$text = @"
hoge0500huge4600telssae0700
hoge0600huge4700telssae0800fdef
"@

$pat = "hoge0(\d{1,})huge4(\d{1,})telssae0(\d{1,})(.*)?"
$regex = [regex]$pat
$regex.Matches($text) | foreach {
    $TEST1 = $_.Groups[1].Value
    $TEST2 = $_.Groups[2].Value
    $TEST3 = $_.Groups[3].Value
    $TEST4 = $_.Groups[4].Value
    $TEST1 = $TEST1 / $WARU
    $TEST2 = $TEST2 / $WARU
    $TEST3 = $TEST3 / $WARU
    Write-Output hoge0${TEST1}huge4${TEST2}telssae0${TEST3}${TEST4}
}
```

イメージとしてはこんな感じです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

グループの値をシンプルに読み取って置換後の数値でフォーマットする方法です。

```
function My-Replace($s) {
    #正規表現で置換
    $x = 2
    $pattern =  "^hoge0(\d+)huge4(\d+)telssae0(\d+)(.*)$" 
    $m = $s | Select-String -Pattern $pattern
    $groups = $m.Matches.Groups
    $arr = 1..3 | %{ $groups[$_].Value / $x}
    $arr += $groups[4].Value
    "hoge0{0}huge4{1}telssae0{2}{3}" -f $arr
}

#hoge.txtを読み込み、fuga.txtとして出力
(Get-Content hoge.txt) -as [string[]] | %{
    My-Replace $_ | Out-File -Append -Encoding default fuga.txt
}
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。重ねての質問で大変申し訳ないのですが、『/2』ではなく『*1.5』にする場合はどうすれば宜しいのでしょうか？（小数点は一桁まで）

Comment: 3行目を`$x = 1.5`に、7行目を`$arr = 1..3 | %{ [int]$groups[$_].Value * $x}`に、9行目を`"hoge0{0:0.#}huge4{1:0.#}telssae0{2:0.#}{3}" -f $arr`に書き換えてください。

Comment: 確かに動作しました。本当にありがとうございます。